# CSS: alinear elemento ajeno a un formulario con los botones de éste

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente estructura para dar de alta a los usuarios en mi página web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente código, que consiste básicamente en un formulario y un archivo adicional para el botón-enlace de "Volver", que es el que quiero alinear con los otros dos botones:

```
<form class="" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=registro.php">

    <h2 class="titulo-registro display-4 text-center mt-5 mb-4">Alta de <span>usuario</span></h2>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="nombre">Tu nombre</label>
        <input class="col-10" id="nombre" type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="25" name="nombre" placeholder="Ejemplo: Indi3_Geek" required/>
        <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
        <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">El nombre o apodo que prefieras con tal de que tenga al menos tres caracteres y no más de veinticinco</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="correo">Un correo</label>
        <input class="col-10" id="correo" type="email" minlength="3" maxlength="100" name="correo" placeholder="Ejemplo: indi3geek@crazymail.org" required/>
        <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
        <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">Utiliza una dirección de correo electrónico que utilices habitualmente en caso de que necesitemos contactar contigo</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="contrasena">Una contraseña</label>
        <input class="col-4" id="contrasena" type="password" name="contrasena" minlength="3" maxlength="25" placeholder="Mejor no dar ejemplos..." required/>
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="contrasena2">Confírmamela, anda</label>
        <input class="col-4" id="contrasena2" type="password" name="contrasena2" minlength="3" maxlength="25" required/>
        <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
        <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">De nuevo, sólo la restricción de los caracteres (entre 3 y 25)</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="enviar" type="submit">¡Adelante!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="reset" onclick ="return confirm('¿Desea borrar todos los datos?')">No me convence</button>
    </div>

</form>

<?php include("volver.php"); ?>
```

El archivo `volver.php` tiene el siguiente código; la web almacena cookies en función de los valores que adquiere `$_POST` para que si a un usuario le da por entrar a la sección de registro y luego quiere salir sin darse de alta, la web sepa a dónde tiene que regresar y no se salga simplemente al index (lo he guardado en un archivo aparte porque ese botón -convertido a enlace- aparece en otras partes de la web):

```
<?php

    if($_COOKIE['inicio_decada'])
    {
        echo '<form method="post" action="index.php?fichero=decadas.php">';
        echo '<button class="boton-volver" role="link" name="inicio_decada" value="'.$_COOKIE['inicio_decada'].'">Volver</button>'; 
        echo '</form>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<form method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php">';
        echo '<button class="boton-volver" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="'.$_COOKIE['recopilatorio'].'">Volver</button>'; 
        echo '</form>';
    }

?>
```

Bueno, entonces, ¿cómo podría hacer para que el botón-enlace de *Volver* apareciese a continuación de los dos botones del formulario?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas tener el botón de "volver" en otro `<form>`?

Comment: Pues la verdad es que probé a meterlo en el mismo y no funcionaba. Al pulsar volver con todos los input vacíos empezaba por quejarse de que el nombre no podía estar vacío.

Comment: Eso te ocurre porque implicitamente los botones son `type="submit"` y entonces te está tratando de enviar un formulario en el cual tienes campos `required`, prueba a ponerle un `type="button"` al botón y mételo dentro del mismo `<form>` y a continuación de los botones de enviar y de reset, te será más sencillo alinearlos.

Comment: ¿`type=button` al botón -o botones- de `volver.php`? En ese caso inutiliza el botón-enlace "Volver".

Comment: Exacto, así no te ejecutará el `submit` al pulsarlos.

Comment: No funciona. Volver queda inutilizado y no se puede regresar a la página anterior. Quizá no estoy haciendo exactamente lo que propones, ¿podrías elaborar un poco más la respuesta?

Comment: Porque lo que hace el botón volver al ser pulsado lo tienes en el `action` del `<form>` que lo envolvía. Al no tenerlo ahora dentro de ese `<form>` debes asignarle un evento `click` para hacerle la redirección desde **Javascript**. Es mejor hacerlo así porque si no el colocarlo junto a los otros botones se va a convertir en un infierno a la hora de realizar el responsive y teniéndolo dentro del mismo `form-group` no.

Comment: La verdad es que no sé por dónde tirar. Si pudieras darme una respuesta detallada te lo agradecería.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96962/discussion-between-phpmyguel-and-javier-blanco).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías solucionarlo así:

- Al formulario de "*Alta de usuario*" debes asignarle un **id** (`ej: formAltaUsuario`)
- Sacar los botones "*¡Adelante!*" y "*No me convence*" fuera del formulario y a ambos asignarle el atributo [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes) con valor igual al **id** del formulario (`eg: form="formAltaUsuario"`).
- Por último poner el `include("volver.php")` junto a los botones.

#### Ejemplo

```html
<form id="formAltaUsuario" class="" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=registro.php">

  <h2 class="titulo-registro display-4 text-center mt-5 mb-4">Alta de <span>usuario</span></h2>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="nombre">Tu nombre</label>
    <input class="col-10" id="nombre" type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="25" name="nombre" placeholder="Ejemplo: Indi3_Geek" required/>
    <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
    <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">El nombre o apodo que prefieras con tal de que tenga al menos tres caracteres y no más de veinticinco</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="correo">Un correo</label>
    <input class="col-10" id="correo" type="email" minlength="3" maxlength="100" name="correo" placeholder="Ejemplo: indi3geek@crazymail.org" required/>
    <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
    <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">Utiliza una dirección de correo electrónico que utilices habitualmente en caso de que necesitemos contactar contigo</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="contrasena">Una contraseña</label>
    <input class="col-4" id="contrasena" type="password" name="contrasena" minlength="3" maxlength="25" placeholder="Mejor no dar ejemplos..." required/>
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="contrasena2">Confírmamela, anda</label>
    <input class="col-4" id="contrasena2" type="password" name="contrasena2" minlength="3" maxlength="25" required/>
    <h6 class="col-2">hola</h6>
    <small class="col-10 form-text text-muted">De nuevo, sólo la restricción de los caracteres (entre 3 y 25)</small>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="enviar" type="submit" form="formAltaUsuario">¡Adelante!</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" form="formAltaUsuario" type="reset" onclick="return confirm('¿Desea borrar todos los datos?')">No me convence</button>
  <?php include("volver.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Gran solución. No sabía que se podían hacer botones de `submit` que lancen formularios sin estar dentro de sus respectivas etiquetas `<form>`. Grande el atributo `form`.